# Cannot open jpg images with PIL or open()

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am testing to save ImageField in Django, but for some reason all the *.jpg files I've tried don't work while the one png I had works.
Using django shell in WSL VCode terminal.

python 3.7

django 3.0

pillow 7.1.2

If I do with open():

```
# this has no error
f = open('loko.jpg', 'rb')

#if I do 
f.read()  # it shows only b'', like its empty

# this saves the field but the image is 0 bytes and cannot be open
object.image.save('name', File(f))
```

If I do with PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

# this shows error
# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'loko.jpg'
img = Image.open('loko.jpg')
```

With the .png image I've tried, both methods work great.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to update the python-pillow package.

Now it works.